# Upload video file to s3 after recording with AMS/FMS

Tags: amazon-s3, flash-media-server

Is it possible to upload a published video file from AMS/FMS over http? Currently I publish the video with a '_temp' appended and use ams File api to rename the file. I've got a C# process watching my ams directory for files without a '_temp' suffix, and when it finds one it uploads it to s3. Surely there is a less complicated way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
I've recently discovered AMS C++ plugins. Seems promising, but complicated. Before I invest the time, is what I want even possible with a plugin? Does an open source plugin that does this already exist?